# Can I say “He has been in Delhi 3 times”?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect

Let's take the sentence.

> **He has lived in Delhi 3 times**.

Is this sentence correct? If it is correct then can I use the following sentence?

> **He has been in Delhi 3 times**.

Is this an example of *present perfect* tense because we've used the participle form '*been*' after '*has*'? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Present Perfect is used for **actions that can be repeated** without mentioning a specific point in time.

> He *has been* **to** Delhi three times.

We use "**[been to](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-been-to)**" when a person visits (*goes to*) a place and returns home. A  living person can visit (*go to*) a place several times in their lifetime, which is why the present perfect tense is preferable in this instance.

> > He has lived in Delhi **three times**.

A person can settle in the same location (e.g. a city) more than once. The sentence above suggests that the person does not live in Delhi today but it does not exclude the possibility of their [taking up residence](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-up-residence) sometime in the future.

> He *has lived* **in** Delhi since 2019

The PP is also used for uninterrupted actions that began in the past and continue to the present.

> He has been **in** Delhi for three days

We use **been in** when someone is still IN that location.

Comment: But present perfect and present perfect continuous are two different tenses. Isn't it ? Present perfect indicates that the action has been completed. On the other hand , present perfect continuous indicates that the action was started in the past and still is continuing. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: You can also use PP for uninterrupted actions, e.g. **I have worked / lived in Japan for twenty years**  VS **I have been working / living in Japan for 20 years**. There is no real significant difference in meaning. However PPC is often used to focus attention on an *action* e.g. **We have been walking all day**, *our feet are killing us*.

Comment: @SahilLaskar See Google book results for ["has lived here for"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+lived+here+for%22&biw=1146&bih=614&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsZsQ-UkeaNBYjQKz_caleN5Ma-3Tg%3A1660116207886&ei=71zzYqLHNeO8xc8P1pG1iA4&ved=0ahUKEwji-uzm3rv5AhVjXvEDHdZIDeEQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22has+lived+here+for%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ5QhY-BFgqR1oAHAAeACAAWmIAaIDkgEDNC4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: Suppose I worked in a company from 2015 to 2018. Then I can say I've worked in a company for three years. Right? So I've three years experience of working there. I might have left the work later. Now if I say I have been working in a company for three years, it means that in 2019 I started working and still in 2022 I'm working there. Isn't it? This is where I'm getting confused. I'm stuck between PP and PPC.

Comment: @SahilLaskar Your analysis is correct but you forget there is context. And a sentence that states "I've worked at Tesla for three years“ has TWO possible interpretations **1.** The person continues to work at Tesla. **2.** The person **used to work** at Tesla but today works for a different company. // Please do not ask more questions in the comments. Your original question mentioned nothing about PPC and in fact my answer does not include it.

Comment: If you left the company in 2018 you would normally say "I worked there for three years."

Comment: @KateBunting yes, that's very true and that is why context is important. An interviewee could list the number of places where they worked : **I've worked for** Tesla, Sony and Linux. The comment section is not the best place to answer questions about the Present Perfect.